# exception in thread main java.lang.nosuchmethoderror main

Tags: java

All my java programs are returning the following error even though every thing is correct in the code. 
exception in thread main java.lang.nosuchmethoderror main

Please find one of my example codes below

```
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList; 
    import java.util.Collections;

    public class ArraySample{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
      public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO code application logic here
            ArrayList <Integer> a = new ArrayList <Integer>();


             a.add(5);
             a.add(2);
             a.add(8);
             a.add(1);
             a.add(0);

             Collections.sort(a,null);
             System.out.println(a);
             Collections.sort(a,Collections.reverseOrder());
             System.out.println(a);


    }
   }
```

I know that the following specific requirements for the entry point method should be met:

The method must be in the nominated class.
The name of the method must be "main" with exactly that capitalization1.
The method must be public.
The method must be static.
The method's return type must be void.
The method must have exactly one argument, and the type of that argument must be String[].

In my code all the requirements are met and also I am encountering such errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how are you running this? `javac ArraySample.java` followed by `java ArraySample` ?

Comment: Copied and pasted into my IDE, can't confirm your problem.

Comment: What method is it complaining about? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Works from the command line for me. Are you sure you've compiled your latest version?

Comment: The problem is not with your code only how you invoke it / environment configuration. Post more info regarding this.

Comment: Reinstall JDK. This works for me.